# How to create jagged array of array of strings

Tags: c, malloc, realloc, jagged-arrays

I am writing a program which takes command line arguments, I want to separate all the arguments using a string "PIPE" for example I can write ls -la PIPE wc. 
My code

```
char **args = argv;
int pipes=0;
while(*args)
{
    if(strcmp("PIPE",*args) == 0)
    {
        pipes++;
    }
    args++;
}
int *pipeIndexes = NULL;
if(pipes > 0)
{
    pipeIndexes=(int *)malloc(pipes*sizeof(int));
    args = argv;
    pipeIndexes[pipes];
    int counter=0,i=0;
    while(*args)
    {
        if(strcmp("PIPE",*args) == 0)
        {
            pipeIndexes = (int *)realloc(pipeIndexes,sizeof(int)*(counter+1));
            pipeIndexes[counter] = i;
            counter++;
        }
        i++;
        args++;
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is I want to create another array which will store arguments for each program? For example.

```
programs = { {"ls","-la"},{"wc"}}
```

Comment: I put an answer with a proposal and execution examples, I added NULL at the end of each built (sub) array to mark the end of them like there is a NULL at the end of argv

Comment: @bruno Thanks I think I forgot to mark is a solution. I have aquestion that why are allocating memory for n+2? I know +1 is for NULL at the end but why + 2?

Comment: is n+2 because +1 for the new element and +1 for the NULL added at the end (n is incremented _after_ the malloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proposal where each (sub) array is ended by a NULL to marks its end, so for instance `ls -la PIPE wc` produces `{ {"ls","-la",NULL},{"wc",NULL},NULL}`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc == 1) {
    puts("at least an argument must be given");
    return -1;
  }

  char *** commands = NULL;
  size_t nCommands = 0;

  do {
    commands = realloc(commands, (nCommands + 2)*sizeof(char **));

    char ** command = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;

    while ((*++argv != NULL) && strcmp(*argv, "PIPE")) {
      command = realloc(command, (n + 2)*sizeof(char *));
      command[n++] = *argv; /* may be strdup(*argv) */
    }
    if (n == 0)
      puts("invalid PIPE");
    else {
      command[n] = NULL; /* marks the end */
      commands[nCommands++] = command;
    }
  } while (*argv);

  if (nCommands == 0)
    puts("no command");
  else {
    commands[nCommands] = NULL; /* marks the end */

    /* debug, print result, free ressources */
    char *** pcommands = commands;

    while (*pcommands) {
      char ** pcommand = *pcommands;

      while (*pcommand)
        printf("%s ", *pcommand++);
      putchar('\n');
      free(*pcommands++);
    }
    free(commands);
  }   
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
/tmp % gcc -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra aa.c
/tmp % ./a.out ls -la PIPE wc
ls -la 
wc 
/tmp % ./a.out ls
ls 
/tmp % ./a.out 
at least an argument must be given
/tmp % ./a.out ls PIPE PIPE wc
invalid PIPE
ls 
wc 
vxl15036 /tmp % ./a.out ls PIPE 
invalid PIPE
ls
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
/tmp % valgrind ./a.out ls -la PIPE wc
==9808== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9808== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9808== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9808== Command: ./a.out ls -la PIPE wc
==9808== 
ls -la 
wc 
==9808== 
==9808== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9808==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9808==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 96 bytes allocated
==9808== 
==9808== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9808== 
==9808== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9808== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you've discovered a use case for `char ***`.  A jagged array in C is best implemented as an array of pointers, so you need an array of (dynamically allocated) arrays of pointers.

In the following snippet (untested), it is left as an exercise to call `realloc` as needed to grow the arrays.

```c
  char ***programs = malloc(10 * sizeof(char **)); /* arbitrary small size */
  int prog = 0, arg = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (strcmp(argv[i], "PIPE") == 0) {
      programs[prog][arg] = NULL;
      arg = 0;
      prog++;
      /* realloc programs if needed */
      programs[prog] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char *));
    } else {
      programs[prog][arg++] = argv[i];
      /* realloc programs[prog] if needed */
    }
  }
  programs[prog][arg] = NULL;
  /* realloc programs if needed */
  programs[++prog] = NULL;
```